# second and third update statements aren't actually updating

Tags: sql

I tried changing the ";" in all different orders and any other way then this doesn't update any columns. But when its like this it only runs the first statement. PS: I'm using mimir if that matters.

This is the code:

```
ALTER TABLE MODEL 
ADD MOD_WAIT_CHG INT(11);


UPDATE MODEL 
SET MOD_WAIT_CHG = 100
WHERE MOD_CODE = 'C-90A';

UPDATE MODEL 
SET MOD_WAIT_CHG = 75
WHERE MOC_CODE = 'PA23-250';

UPDATE MODEL 
SET MOD_WAIT_CHG = 50
WHERE MOC_CODE = 'PA31-350';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of `MOC_CODE` You must type  `MOD_CODE`
and also you Cannot specify a **column width** on data type `int`.

for this situation better to use Transaction as bellow:

```
begin transaction;

    ALTER TABLE MODEL ADD MOD_WAIT_CHG INT;

    UPDATE MODEL SET MOD_WAIT_CHG = 100 WHERE MOD_CODE = 'C-90A';
    
    UPDATE MODEL SET MOD_WAIT_CHG = 75 WHERE MOD_CODE = 'PA23-250';
    
    UPDATE MODEL SET MOD_WAIT_CHG = 50 WHERE MOD_CODE = 'PA31-350';
 commit;
```